# calling stored procedure which returns multiple rows using JOOQ

Tags: mysql, jooq

I have a MySQL procedure which simply returns all rows .How to invoke that procedure using JOOQ ?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P_GET_ALL()
SELECT * FROM T_EMPS
```

Answer (score 1):

Here all you need - follow this [link](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.0/manual/sql-execution/stored-procedures/)

Example :

```
P_GET_ALLprocedure = new P_GET_ALL();
procedure.execute(configuration);
```

To get the result :

```
assertEquals(new datatype("12"), procedure.getColName());
```

Comment: But what about the type of the result ? . How to read the result ?

Comment: @user3415648: Unfortunately, the type of cursors returned from stored procedures cannot be known from procedure metadata (to our knowledge). All type information must be obtained at run time from the `Result` object